# Какой тип данных у значений *args и **kwargs?

Tags: python, python-3.x

К какому типу данных относятся значения `*args` и `**kwargs`?

Comment: list и dict соответственно. https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/482464/ надеюсь тут можно кидать ссылки на другие источники

Comment: @AnatolyKritskiy, можно, если не спам. В том числе в ответах, но ответ только из ссылки не должен состоять, ссылка может быть приведена как источник или для дополнительной информации.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это можно самостоятельно проверить

Но забегу вперед:

- `args` - кортеж, `tuple` (хотя я ожидал, что будет `list`)
- `kwargs` - словарь, `dict`

Сделаем код для проверки:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print(type(args))
    print(type(kwargs))
```

Без параметров:

```
foo()
# <class 'tuple'>
# <class 'dict'>
```

С параметрами:

```
foo(1, "2", [], a=1, b="2", c=[])
# <class 'tuple'>
# <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: тоже думал что *args это list. удивлён

Comment: @AnatolyKritskiy А не надо бы удивляться. Всё, что не предполагается изменять, питон предпочитает хранить в кортежах. Если посмотреть интерфейсы популярных библиотек, там всё, что нужно указывать в виде конкретного вида коллекции, указывается кортежами. Кортежи быстрее, компактнее и безопаснее (за счёт иммутабельности).

Comment: @CrazyElf, все правильно сказали :)